# Visual Studio 2019 Entity Framework Enable Migrations Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a small ASP.NET web application, but for some reason I have an issue with migrations after type in Package Manager console:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

Console throws this error

> Enable-Migrations : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-Migrations
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations

I use Visual Studio 2019 and have installed Entity Framework 6.3.0 via NugGet Package Manager. Also have a `DbContext` class in my `models` folder

I've tried a lot of solutions that I saw other people have made, but none of them works. Hope someone has similar problem.

P.S
Project structure is

```
Project
    - Connected Services
    - Properties
    - References
    - App_Data
    - App_Start
    - Content
    - Controllers
    - fonts
    - Models
    - Scripts
    - Views
    - favicon.iso
    - Global.asax
    - packages.config
    - Web.config
```

Comment: Can you publish your solution structure in vs?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/1290 <-- The workarounds provided there do work.

Comment: @Oleg i update the issue.

Comment: Try to removed EF6.3.0. from your project and then re-added it, please restart visual studio before this. Besides, install the latest update for visual studio 2019.

Comment: @madreflection your answer was correct about workaround and it works for now, hope they fix it i with next update of EF
Thanks both of you

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Eu tive esse mesmo problema em um projeto pessoal, e após algumas horas de teste consegui resolver da seguinte forma:
1 - Acesse Ferramentas > Gerenciador de pacotes do NuGet > Gerenciador de pacotes do NuGet para solução.

2 -  Desinstale o EntityFramework 6.3.0  "que foi o meu caso", e instale a versão 6.2.0, feito isso, Recompilar Solução, em seguida rode o comando > Enable-Migrations

[Enable Migration success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4fiM.png)

Comment: Please use english on your questions and answers while you are on regular `stackoverflow`, refer to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ instead.